# WordPress Multisite - Create New Sites and Users through API?

Tags: php, wordpress, api, xml-rpc

I have created a Wordpress multisite and was wondering if it was possible to programatically add new sites (blogs) and users through the API?

Basically I have another website (ASP.Net C#) where I will be selling something and I want to give users a free blog everytime they buy something. So everytime a user registers on my other website I want to connect to wordpress multisite through the API and create a new blog for the user.

I have looked through some of the documentation on XML-RPC and saw stuff about adding new blog posts but is it possible to add actual blogs too? Or if not, is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi: Like a year ago i had the same problem. Im not sure if it is possible to create it using the API. We solved at that time creating the tables automatically with php scripts. An easy way is to have the wordpress core tables, and everytime a new user register, you just copy the wp core tables into new wp tables but with a new prefix. That way you just personalize some fields like blog title.
You can contact me is you think I can help.